# what is the benefit of using classloader hierarchy?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

EDIT:

Can we not dump all the jars on the jre/lib folder of the jdk and use the BootstrapClassLoader as the only classloader ?

Comment: There is totally unclear what is the question. Are you tried to point on some facts that you got, or what? Please, edit your question to be clear enough for all the people which may want to answer on it.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I have edited the question.

Comment: So you want to know why there's a distinction between the bootstrap classloader and the system classloader? Or why there might be additional classloaders beyond the system classloader?

Comment: @the8472 -I would like to know "Why there might be additional classloaders beyond the system classloader?"

Comment: You are overlooking everything of interest: JAR versioning, what happens on reinstallation or upgrade of the JRE, keeping container classes away from webapp classes; ... all the reasons why multiple classloaders are useful.

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap class loader has a special purpose which is to load the built in classes.  It is the only class loader which can do this. When you add a URL ClassLoader it can load additional JAR/directories but these cannot contain he built in packages.  This prevents the JVM from being hacked.

In short the minimum is two, the system class loader and the user's class loader.

Comment: @Peter-We can  create our own classloader and override the loadClass method While doing so we need not implement delegation model and the Custom classloader might just load the classes loaded by bootstrap classloader.

Comment: @RahulMathur except it won't let you, but you can try.

Comment: How is JVM going to stop me?
Does it maintain a list of the files on lib/ext and throw ClassNotFound Exception if the class name matches any item on the list ?

Comment: @RahulMathur it has a list of packages you can't load unless you are using the boot class loader e.g. java. and jdk.internal.

Answer (score 0):

Each project has a different set of dependencies (and different versions). Classloaders cannot handle different versions of the same class nicely - they just take the first class they find on their classpth with the name (say, com.example.MyClass (At least, till everything is modularized in JDK 9). So, you want each project to load classes from a different path, instead of a common path. For example, maven projects load their dependencies from $HOME/.m2/repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why and where would we need to have different versions of a dependency ?

Comment: On a machine, typically, there will be multiple Java programs (just like there will be multiple C/Python/Perl/Ruby programs). They each can have different versions of the dependencies like logging library.